# Completing my recursive SQL operation, is cte a good choice for me?

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, while-loop, common-table-expression

I have the following data:

```
TestData
Code | RowNum |
123  | 1      |
456  | 2      |
789  | 3      |
```

What I am trying to accomplish is a cycle through this data, checking a separate table to see if any records are `LIKE` these codes. Here is what I have tried, but I am returning `0` records at the end. I believe I could possibly use a cte to accomplish this, but I'm having some trouble understanding the base idea of recursive cte. Am I going the wrong direction here? Below is the query I have which is returning `0` records.

```
DECLARE @myCounter int = 0;
WHILE (@myCounter < @ROWCOUNT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Code nvarchar(8) = (SELECT [Code]
                                 FROM [MyTable]
                                 WHERE [RowNum] = @myCounter);
    SELECT *
    FROM [RefTable]
    WHERE [Code] LIKE '%' + @Code + '%';
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this should be done with a single query using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT m.RowNum, m.Code, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM MyTable m
LEFT JOIN RefTable r ON ( r.Code LIKE '%' + m.Code + '%' )
GROUP BY m.RowNum, m.Code
ORDER BY m.RowNum
```

Use a `JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` to ignore rows without entries instead of displaying `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll help a whole lot, but if you're trying to match code to another table, you can always do a join with a LIKE condition and potentially avoid the recursive search.

```
SELECT * FROM T1
RIGHT JOIN T2
ON T1.CODE LIKE '%' + T2.CODE + '%'
```